Z3 Towers Solver
I'm trying to write a solver using Z3's .NET library for the Towers puzzle format. Adding the constraints for "every row and column has a distinct permutation of 1-5" is simple enough, especially cribbing from the Sudoku solver provided as an example for Z3. However, I am stuck on the "Exactly X towers are visible from the left/right/top/bottom of each row/column" constraint, and specifically checking how many towers are visible from each point. It should be as simple as
int tallestSoFar = 0;
int towersSoFar = 0;
int[] section = X[i];
for (int ii = 0; ii < section.Length; ii++)
{
    if (section[ii] > tallestSoFar)
    {
        tallestSoFar = section[ii];
        towersSoFar++;
    }
}

However, this does not work when X and section are made of IntExpr's rather than actual ints. How would I express this in the syntax Z3 would recognize?

The main issue here is that if of the host language only works on "concrete" values. Instead, you'll have to use the if-then-else construct to represent a symbolic choice. In different bindings, this is called a different name. In z3py, it's If. In .NET it's MkITE. Each host language will have a slightly different name/calling convention.
The idea is to represent the conditional using a symbolic expression. (For instance, tallestSoFar will have to be an expression built out of MkITE nodes that represent its value.
As a side note, I'd recommend using a much friendlier API, like that of z3py for instance, instead of .NET, especially if you're new to Z3. Symbolic programming can be tricky, and API's in C/C++/.NET tend to be a lot more verbose and harder to use correctly. Prefer z3py, or perhaps a binding in some other high-level language like Haskell or Racket. APIs from .NET/C/C++ should only be preferred if you really have to program in those languages for some other reason, as they tend to be much lower level.
